# How to show error text in TextFormField in Flutter below it and not in it

Tags: flutter

I have sign up page where user has to enter info in text form field. I have added validator that field can't be empty or min of 5 or xyz characters should be entered to pass through. My question is how can I make the error message display below the form field rather than in the field. this is the code :

```
child: TextFormField(
                                          obscureText: isHidden,
                                          controller: _nameController,
                                          validator: (value) {
                                            RegExp regex = RegExp(r'^.{5,}$');
                                            if (value!.isEmpty) {
                                              return ("Password can't be empty");
                                            }
                                            if (!regex.hasMatch(value)) {
                                              return ("Minimum of 5 characters Required");
                                            }
                                            return null;
                                          },
                                          onSaved: (value) {
                                            shopName.text = value!;
                                          },
                                          
                                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                                            border: InputBorder.none,
                                            errorStyle: TextStyle(
                                                color: Colors.red[400],
                                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                                fontSize: 13,
                                                height: 0),
                                            contentPadding:
                                                EdgeInsets.only(left: 15),
                                            // fillColor: Colors.blueAccent,
                                            suffix: Padding(
                                              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                                  right: 8.0),
                                              child: InkWell(
                                                  onTap: _passwdview,
                                                  child: isHidden
                                                      ? const Icon(
                                                          Icons.visibility,
                                                          color: Colors.blue,
                                                          size: 20,
                                                        )
                                                      : const Icon(
                                                          Icons.visibility_off,
                                                          color: Colors.blue,
                                                          size: 20,
                                                        )),
                                            ),
                                            hintText: 'Enter Password',
                                          ),
                                        ),
```

[image]

I want something like this : [image]

Comment: So you want it like the image? Or you want to separate widget for error?

Comment: I have edited the question with example image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`main.dart` file:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(30),
          child: MyWidget(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextFormField(
      validator: (value) {
        RegExp regex = RegExp(r'^.{5,}$');
        if (value!.isEmpty) {
          return ("Password can't be empty");
        }
        if (!regex.hasMatch(value)) {
          return ("Minimum of 5 characters Required");
        }
        return null;
      },
      autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        errorStyle: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.red[400],
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            fontSize: 13,
            height: 0),
        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15),
        enabledBorder: InputBorders.enabled,
        errorBorder: InputBorders.error,
        focusedErrorBorder: InputBorders.error,
        border: InputBorders.border,
        focusedBorder: InputBorders.focused,
        hintText: 'Enter Password',
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

`constants.dart` file

```
class InputBorders {
  InputBorders._();

  static const border = OutlineInputBorder(
    borderRadius: Radiuses.r8,
    borderSide: BorderSide(
      color: ColorPalette.strokeGrey,
      width: 0.8,
    ),
  );

  static const enabled = OutlineInputBorder(
    borderRadius: Radiuses.r8,
    borderSide: BorderSide(
      color: ColorPalette.strokeGrey,
      width: 0.8,
    ),
  );

  static const error = OutlineInputBorder(
    borderRadius: Radiuses.r8,
    borderSide: BorderSide(
      color: ColorPalette.red,
      width: 0.8,
    ),
  );

  static const success = OutlineInputBorder(
    borderRadius: Radiuses.r8,
    borderSide: BorderSide(
      color: ColorPalette.greenDark,
      width: 0.8,
    ),
  );

  static const focused = OutlineInputBorder(
    borderRadius: Radiuses.r8,
    borderSide: BorderSide(
      color: ColorPalette.blueLight,
      width: 0.8,
    ),
  );
}

class ColorPalette {
  ColorPalette._();

  static const blueLight = Color(0xFF5599FB);
  static const greenDark = Color(0xFF219653);
  static const red = Color(0xFFFF0033);
  static const strokeGrey = Color(0xFFB4B4B4);
}

class Radiuses {
  Radiuses._();

  static const r8 = BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8));
}
```

Empty State:

[image: 1]

Focused State:

[image: 2]

Error State:

[image: 3]

Answer (score 0):

Use [autovalidateMode](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FormField/autovalidateMode.html) property.

> If AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction, this FormField will only auto-validate after its content changes. If AutovalidateMode.always, it will auto-validate even without user interaction. If AutovalidateMode.disabled, auto-validation will be disabled.

Comment: This is actually helpful, I will using this. Thanks. I have revised the question. This was not exactly what I wanted to ask. But surely this is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can checkout the following textfield:

```
TextFormField(
              onChanged: (value) {},
              onSaved: (value) {},
              focusNode: FocusNode(),
              autofocus: false,
              style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 14, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                fillColor: Colors.grey[300],
                filled: true,
                isDense: true,
                contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 12.0, horizontal: 16.0),
                // counter: Container(),
                counterText: '',
                hintStyle: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 14),
                hintText: 'Give me Blood',
                errorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Colors.red),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
                ),
                focusedErrorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Colors.red),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
                ),
                focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Colors.black),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
                ),
                enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Colors.green),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
                ),
              ),
              validator: (value) {
                RegExp regex = RegExp(r'^.{5,}$');
                if (value!.isEmpty) {
                  return ("Password can't be empty");
                }
                if (!regex.hasMatch(value)) {
                  return ("Minimum of 5 characters Required");
                }
                return null;
              }),
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest of all is to use `TextFormField` with `validator`

```
TextFormField(
  // The validator receives the text that the user has entered.
  validator: (value) {
    if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
      return 'Please enter some text';
    }
    return null;
  },
),
```

For alternatives,follow the official documentation examples: https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/forms/validation